# Ajax stops working after enabling URL re-routing

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am loading some content using AJAX and ASP.NET web-methods. Following is the code for Ajax:

```
var pageIndex = 1;
var pageCount;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        GetRecords();
    }
});
function GetRecords() {
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TopicList.aspx/GetTopics",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }

        }
        );

    }
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
    var topics = xml.find("Topics");

    topics.each(function () {
        var table = $("#dvTopics table").eq(0).clone(true);

        var topic = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TopicList.aspx/LoadTopicRow",
            data: "{message: '" + topic.find("desid").text() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                table.append(r.d);
            }
        });
        $("#dvTopics").append(table);

    });

    $("#loader").hide();
}
```

The code was working fine until I enabled URL rewriting and changed the rule for web-method containing page(i.e. `TopicList.aspx`) to `ContentViewer/{view}`.

Now the web-method is not being called by AJAX.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a shot in the dark since you havent included detail on any errors. Try changing your url 
from:

```
url: "TopicList.aspx/LoadTopicRow",
```

to

```
url: "TopicList/LoadTopicRow",
```